# How to get the explicit result of this limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let $f(x) = x^2+1$. I would like to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{k \to +\infty} k \int_0^1 \sin \left [ \left ( k + \frac{1}{2}  \right ) \pi x  \right ] f(x)  \, \mathrm d x.
$$

Then I use the command

```
Limit[Integrate[k * Sin[( k + 1 / 2) * Pi * x] * (x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 1}], k -> Infinity]
```

Mathematica returns `Indeterminate`

[image]

Could you explain how to get the explicit limit? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Nasser I have corrected the code. It is strange to me because the limit seems to be $1 / \pi$. I have verified it by computing the integral for big values of $k$.

Comment: You are right, it should be 1/pi  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THAm6.png)

Comment: The limit does not exists because it oscillates around `1/pi` with no decreasing amplitude of oscillations so Mathematica is right.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I actually proved that the limit exists in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822733/brezis-exercise-8-28-10-prove-that-there-exists-a-constant-a-in-mathbbr) thread. I just want to confirm it with Mathematica.

Comment: @Akira: So then your proof is wrong.

Comment: @azerbajdzan You can have a look at below answer.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I agree that the limit exists only if $k$ is taken to be natural numbers.

Comment: So then your question is wrongly stated.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Yess, I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DiscreteLimit[k Integrate[Sin[(k + 1/2)*Pi*x]*(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 1}], 
 k -> Infinity]
```

> `1/π`

Also,

```
Series[Integrate[k Sin[(k + 1/2)*Pi*x]*(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 1}], {k, 
   Infinity, 0}] // Normal
```

gives almost the answer

> `1/π + (2 Sin[k π])/π`

**Edit:** From the documentation we read

> DiscreteLimit is also known as discrete limit or limit over the
> integers.

which is my understanding of the basic difference between this and `Limit`

**Edit 2:**
Thanks to @BobHanlon

The corresponding `Series` to the `DiscreteLimit` is given by

```
Series[Integrate[k Sin[(k + 1/2)*Pi*x]*(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 1}], {k, Infinity, 0}, Assumptions -> k ∈ PositiveIntegers] // Normal
```

and evaluates to the expected result.

Comment: Could you explain why `DiscreteLimit` works but `Limit` does not?

Comment: @Akira I added my understanding of the difference between the two

Comment: Voila, this subtlety is important. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This is not a good answer to this question because OP do not ask for limit over integers and your answer makes an impression that the limit over reals is same as over integers. But the limit over reals does not exist while over integers exists in this case.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Some people should focus their efforts on **READING** carefully what is written in the reply. According to the timestamps I already had added my edit. Hence, it is very clear that `DiscreteLimit` is taken over the integers. It is, also, very clear that this differentiates `DiscreteLimit` from `Limit`. Thanks for your comment. It was not a good one.

Comment: @Akira glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: Since you are looking at the `DiscreteLimit`, the corresponding `Series` is `Series[Integrate[k Sin[(k + 1/2)*Pi*x]*(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 1}], {k, Infinity, 0}, Assumptions -> k \[Element] PositiveIntegers] // Normal` which evaluates to the expected `1/Pi`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks a lot. I updated my answer including your comment!

Comment: @Tim not yet, but it's still early. Most deadlines are still open.

Answer (score 2):

No need to only consider `Element[k,Integers]`

```
Integrate[k Sin[(k + 1/2)*Pi*x]*(x^2 + 1), {x, 0, 1}] 
Asymptotic[%, k -> Infinity]// Collect[#, k] &
```

$\frac{2 \sin (\pi  k)}{\pi }+\frac{-\frac{\sin (\pi  k)}{\pi }+\frac{2 \cos(\pi  k)}{\pi ^2}-\frac{1}{2 \pi}}{k}+\frac{1}{\pi }$

Comment: While this is the asymptotic behavior, it is not a limit. Taking the `Limit` of this result gives `Indeterminate` and taking the `DiscreteLimit` gives `1/Pi`

Comment: @BobHanlon For `k->Infinity` we get `1/Pi+2 Sin[Pi k]/Pi` which is indead `Indeterminate`! Restriction `Element[k,Integers]` gives the correct result `1/Pi`!